# .Net 2.0 custom controls and WPF

Tags: wpf

out of curiosity i just want to know those custom control which was developed in .Net 2.0 version that can be reused in WPF application. if yes then what would be the process. usually we add custom control to the toolbox and just drag & drop those onto form and easily manipulate and work with them. so can we follow the same step to include those custom control developed with .net v2.0 onto WPF form or not. please discuss. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse Windows Forms Controls in a WPF application (and the reverse is also true, you can host WPF controls in a Windows Forms application) .

Here is an official documentation link on this subject: [Walkthrough: Hosting a Windows Forms Composite Control in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750944.aspx)